# Private, local (and app specific) modules

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js app with following structure:

```js
+
|-- app/
|   |-- config.js
|   |-- modules/     // MVC app modules/components.
|       |-- login/
|       |-- signup/
|-- lib/             // App specific modules/libraries.
|   |-- auth/
|   |-- storage/
|-- node_modules/    // 3rd party modules.
|   |-- express/
|   |-- hjs/
|-- public/
|-- app.js
|-- package.json
```

What are the options to `require` modules from *lib/* inside - for example - the login module, but without having to specify the relative path?

```js
// app/modules/login/index.js

var auth = require('../../../lib/auth'); // <-- I'd rather have require('auth')

module.exports = function(app) {    
    app.get('/', auth.ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
        res.send('/');
    });    
};
```

I do not want to host modules in *lib/* on Github and would like to keep the *node_modules* directory for 3rd party modules only.

[Modular web applications with Node.js and Express](https://vimeo.com/56166857) (see 2:25) by TJ looks very promising when he talks about `bundledDependencies`. But that [doesn't seem to work yet](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2442).

**Update:**
I've now flattened my structure a little and decided to embrace relative paths instead.

Comment: Is setting `$NODE_PATH` an option?

Comment: If there is another way, I would rather not do that since there is no option on setting it on Heroku et al.

Comment: You could use `module.paths.push(__dirname + '/../lib/')` from within (say) `app/config.js`, although it feels a bit dirty...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Robert :) Wasn't `module.paths` removed some time ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions here.

1. Make [links](https://npmjs.org/doc/link.html) to your modules.
2. Install your modules. To do so, go to the root of your application and type:

`npm install ./lib/storage`

You can install your modules "dynamically" when you start your app.js by executing the previous command.

Comment: ad 1) Are those real Symlinks, meaning updates to my original module in *lib/* would be available as soon as I save the file, right?
ad 2) But then I would need to do that again on every start?

Comment: That is true. But don't forget that symlinks don't work on some Windows versions. The second option may be the best option for you. And yes you would need to install your modules on every starts, you can make a bash script to install them all tho.